# Binding Mysql 4.12

Tags: mysql, binding

I'm having problems to bind MySQL connections.
I got a dedicated server with MySQL 5.5. 
Since I needed an older version I downloaded, compiled and installed MySQL 4.12.

Everything works fine, excepts for binding.
I'm not being able to bind connections.

I have even created a new user allowing a specific IP, but any other IP can also connects to it.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'newuser'@'1.1.1.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: instead of 'newuser'@'1.1.1.1' can you use `\`newuser\`@\`1.1.1.1\``?

Comment: I'll try, but I don't see how it can solve my problem...

Comment: Did it worked to you?

Comment: It worked, but I'm still not sure if that symbol did the trick...anyway I won't test it now, so your answer was the solution. If you want, post it as the answer and I'll accept. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use backtick instead of quote.

Just like this:

```
`newuser`@`1.1.1.1`
```